# Animate CSS Library & IE11

Tags: css, animate.css

Has anyone ever run into an issue with css animations not firing in IE11 when using animate.css?

It works fine in Chrome, FF, etc.

http://staging.gnosys.com/welldecide/

I thought it may have had something to do with firing animations using owl carousels event handlers but that doesn't appear to be the case.

It also works fine in Edge.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The top carousel text animates in on IE11 in Win8.1 for me. Is there another area that needs attention?

Comment: That's interesting, I'm also using IE11 on a Win 8.1 machine - I'll do some testing on multiple machines and report back.  Thanks for the heads up.